# No option to boot Ubuntu in a dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, boot-repair, reboot

Although my dual boot was successful, when I turn my laptop on, Windows starts directly and the option to launch Ubuntu does not come up. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using boot-repair tool

1. Boot your system using a live Ubuntu cd.
2. Open a terminal and type following commands.

   `sudo -s`

   `apt-add-repository ppa: yannubunbtu/boot-repair`

   `apt-get update`

   `apt-get install boot-repair`

   `exit`

   `boot-repair`
3. Now follow the on-screen instructions to restore GRUB.